# Function calling at the left side of the expression

Tags: c++, function, static

Can we have a function calling at the left side of the expression?
This code snippet works well but how? How can a `function calling` can be at left side and please elaborate how this snippet is executing and working well and what if i wouldn't have used `static int` in function definition.Thanks in advance.

```
  #include<iostream>

using namespace std;


int &fun()
{
   static int x; 
   return x;
}    

int main()
{
   fun() = 10;

   /* this line prints 10 on screen */
   printf(" %d ", fun());

   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fun()` is not a function declaration. It's a function call, which is itself an expression. Since this particular call returns an lvalue, it's perfectly fine for it to appear on the left hand side of an assignment. You may want to review the chapter about references in your favorite C++ textbook.

Comment: If you wouldn't have used `static int`, then that line of code would have read simply `x;`, and that would be a syntax error. I suppose I don't understand this part of your question.

Comment: @ Igor Tandetnik ,sorry for writing it as function declaration but how can a function calling accept something ,it can return but how can it accept. And why it is syntax error when i remove static from declaration of variable x ,sorry for inconvenience ,i am newbie in c++.

Comment: Again, a function can return an lvalue - a reference to an object. The assignment then modifies that object.

Comment: @Shivanshu "how can a function calling accept something" suggests you have an incorrect model of how assignment works. The function call doesn't accept anything. The function returns the location of some object in memory. That's the end of the function call. It's `main` which then does something with that object (namely, assign to it).

Comment: Learn about how references work. Notice the `&` on the function return type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any expression that returns a non-const **lvalue** can be on the left side of the **assignment** and function call is also an expression like any other. Since **lvalue** historically means exactly that - **value on the left side** this turns into a recursive definition. So instead you can consider an **lvalue** anything that you can take address of:

```
int x = 5;
&x; //valid, takes the address of the variable
&5; //invalid, integer literal has no address

int func1();
&func1(); //invalid, can't take the address of the temporary value

int &func2();
&func2(); //valid, since the function returned reference
          //which itself is almost the same as the address
```

So any expression that results in something **addressable** can be assigned to. You can even do something like this:

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int z = 5;
(z > 5 ? x : y) = 10;
```

As for your second question, if you remove `static` from your function you would return a reference to a local variable of the function. Local variables stop existing when the function exits, so you would return a reference to a variable that is already destroyed. This, however, will compile and run, but the results of that execution would be unpredictable that's why this is called **undefined behavior**.

Comment: Nice explanation and thanks to efface my doubt about lvalue.